Capture higher degree trend coefficients on iPad Numbers app?
I see there’s a way to capture slope and intercept for a linear trend according to Numbers.app Chart Trendline Equation Capture  and its answers, but I’m using a polynomial trend in Numbers on an iPad and I see no way to even see the trend formula on my chart. I would like to have a way to do both.
